# how to exclude property-sort-order from scss-lint rules?

Tags: css, sass, lint

I have a sasslint.yml file with a a list of rules

One of them is

```
property-sort-order: 1
```

I have tried to exclude it with

```
property-sort-order: enabled:false
```

and with

```
scss-lint --exclude-linter PropertySortOrder
```

But all this unsuccessful.
Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: All you need to do is **provide an empty array** there. I use json instead of YML, so was pretty easy and that worked for me. Not sure how you provide empty array in YML.

Answer (score 3):

You configure `scss-lint` in yml a configuration file. The default is `.scss-lint.yml`, and you can specify a different file via the command line with `--config` (I think `-c` works too). The documentation covers this here: https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint#configuration

You disable a linter with

```
linters:
  LinterName:
    enabled: false
```

Judging by https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/issues/132,

```
linters:
  PropertySortOrder:
    enabled: false
```

will work correctly.

If you'd actually rather not turn it off completely, configuration options for `scss-lint`'s `property-sort-order` are documented here https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/blob/master/lib/scss_lint/linter/README.md#propertysortorder